# Running a python file does nothing, not even an error message

Tags: python, windows, command-line, pip

I guess this one isn't hard to answer but I couldnt find a solution on the internet (that worked for me). Basically I'm trying to install pip on Windows 10. I have the get-pip.py file, I have Python 3.7.5 added to `Path`. Now the correct step would be to execute it, but nothing happens on my command prompt:

```
C:\Users\admin>python get-pip.py

C:\Users\admin>
```

Same happens with `py get-pip.py` and `python3 get-pip-py`, it just skips a line and nothing changed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In Windows, Python already has pip installed, unless for some reason you chose to disable installing it. Run `py -m pip`.

Comment: Python scripts are not required to produce output.  What are you expecting to see, and why are you expecting that?  Have you tested your environment, by running some kind of HelloWorld script?

Comment: Regarding "python3", the standard installation doesn't include a `python3` command. Check `where python3` to see what that's running. It may be the installer for the Microsoft Store app distribution, which should open the store to let you install that particular distribution of Python, but otherwise it does nothing, like you observed.

Comment: oh well, it now works. I remember it used to work some time ago, but I forgot that I had to use the -m option. Thank you! (Edit: Eryk Sun's answer helped me)